# Recent items to attach in Outlook are different

Tags: outlook

Outlook has updated and recent items are not listed in the options. There are some items stored in the cloud, not the recent ones. How to fix it, please?

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific? What recent items do you mean?

Comment: I added a picture.